# First startup of mongod fires up multiple mongod processes

Tags: linux, mongodb

Given a clean mongo data directory, I run a start up script like this (I realise I could use `service`, but that's a different issue and I'm using this script as a workaround):

```
>$ cat startMongo.sh
nohup sudo mongod --rest --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf > logs/mongo.log 2>&1 &
```

The problem is this somehow start lots of processes:

```
>$ ps -efw | grep mongo
root      7038     1  0 21:29 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo mongod --rest --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf
root      7039  7038  0 21:29 pts/0    00:00:00 mongod --rest --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf
root      7040  7039  0 21:29 ?        00:00:00 mongod --rest --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf
root      7041  7040 10 21:29 ?        00:00:01 mongod --rest --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

I *think* this is happening whilst Mongo does some preallocations, which I can see in the log file. After a while, the do disappear:

```
>$ ps -efw | grep mongo
root      7041     1  4 21:29 ?        00:00:01 mongod --rest --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

My question is whether this *should* be happening? I tried the same in Windows, and didn't see an issue. I'm sure this didn't manifest in Ubuntu until recently either (I upgraded from 2.6 to 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run `mongod --fork` and I got:

`about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.`

I guess this means that the main process does some stuff before actually forking to the final listener porcess, and this stuff can be allocating the journal file. I also got the multiple process status you are describing.

I tried the same command without `--fork` and a there was no extra process.

So what you think is correct, the extra spawned `mongod` are there for preallocation, but only in `--fork` mode.

Anyway, using `nohup` at this point is useless, because if you run mongo with `--fork` you are sending it into background mode as well: your nohup log would record only something like :

```
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections. 
forked process: 7306 
child process started successfully, parent exiting
```